# RxJS: How to emit http subscribe in an interval with concatMap or switchMap? What's the difference?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I tried to follow this example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zo5h39) and the [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables) documentations but it doesn't seem to work for me.  Frankly, I'm new to RxJS and don't quite know how to make it work with http and subscribe. Starring at this problem for so long, my brain is mush. Essentially I want `subscribe` to check for new data every interval.  Maybe there is a better way than rxjs?

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Weather } from './interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css']
})
export class WeatherComponent implements  OnInit {
  weathers: any;
  response: any;
  // t = Observable.interval(1000).take(5);
  // numbers = interval(1000);
  // takeFourNumbers = interval(50000).pipe(take(2));


  private serviceUrl = 'https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/OKX/36,38/forecast';
  n = 10000;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {

      this.response = this.http.get<Weather>(this.serviceUrl );
      this.response.subscribe(
        results => {
          this.weathers = results.properties.periods.slice(0, 2);

          // this.numbers.subscribe(x => console.log('Next: ', x));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an http call every 2 minutes with RXJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809224/how-to-make-an-http-call-every-2-minutes-with-rxjs)

Comment: Don't spam the service every second. You will most likely get blocked as a potential DOS attack. Where does the weather change second by second. Polling every ten minutes should be just fine.

Comment: Thank you for reminding the etiquette of not spamming.  I'll make a longer interval.  Also, I find the solution below to be more precise and elegant than other similar solutions on SO.  But if everyone thinks I should delete this question.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `interval` to emit every second and then turn each emission into an HTTP request.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interval(1000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.http.get<Weather>(this.serviceUrl)),
).subscribe(result => {
  // ...
});
```

You might want to use `concatMap` instead of `switchMap` depending on what behavior you want.